# How can I express $f_{xy}$ in polar form?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

Let $x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$. Consider a function $f(x,y)$.

Express $f_{xy}$ in polar form.

How should I proceed here? Should I differentiate $f(x,y)$ twice and find $f_{xy}$, and then replace $x$ and $y$ with $r\cos\theta$ and $r\sin\theta$? Or can I replace $x$ and $y$ with $r\cos\theta$ and $r\sin\theta$ in $f(x,y)$ itself and then differentiate with respect to $r$ and $\theta$?

Is $f_{xy}(x,y) = f_{r\theta}(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=f_{\theta r}(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$?

Comment: Hint : Better to write $g(r,\theta)$ for $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta).$ Then from the chain rule,
$$
g_r(r,\theta)=f_x(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\cos\theta+f_y(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\sin\theta\,.
$$